# How to tell if fonts are embedded in a Microsoft Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, documents, embedded

How can I confirm whether or not fonts are embedded in a Microsoft Word document? I already know [the process to enable embedding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290952) in Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your link, there's a checkbox in the Options > Save dialog which sets this. But unlike most Options settings which are global, this one is document-specific, so will also tell you whether fonts are already embedded in your document.