# custom fonts in .doc & .pdf documents

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, webserver

I am using my own custom font for my .doc and .pdf documents. Now I want to make these files public (upload on my FTP-server). Is there a way for the other user to see the documents rendered with custom font, without having it installed on their systems? Or a way to embed the font?

Comment: Yes. What are you using to create the documents?

Comment: @iglvzx Microsoft Word 2007/2010

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290952 & http://superuser.com/questions/22445/how-to-tell-if-fonts-are-embedded-in-a-microsoft-word-document & http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295062 & http://superuser.com/questions/378353/save-as-pdf-on-microsoft-word-2007-isnt-embedding-the-fonts & http://superuser.com/questions/313842/searching-for-a-word-to-pdf-converter-that-will-handle-special-fonts  <--- just to get you started, and to see some of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

PDF definitively allows you to embed your fonts (as long as their type is one of the standard ones: TrueType, Type1, etc.).

And every compliant PDF viewer should have no problem to correctly and truthfully render any embedded font.